# Providing a Read Only List of Classes in C#

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I have a set of custom data types that can be used to manipulate basic blocks of data. For example:

```
MyTypeA Foo = new MyTypeA();
Foo.ParseString(InputString);
if (Foo.Value > 4) return;
```

Some of these types define read-only properties that describe aspects of the types (for example a name, bit size, etc.).

In my custom framework I want to be able to provide these types to the user for use in their applications but I also want to give the user a list of the available types which they could easily bind to a combobox. My current approach:

```
public static class DataTypes
{
    static ReadOnlyCollection<MyDataType> AvailableTypes;

    static DataTypes()
    {
        List<MyDataType> Types = new List<MyDataType>();
        Types.Add(new MyTypeA());
        Types.Add(new MyTypeB());
        AvailableTypes = new ReadOnlyCollection<MyDataType>(Types);
    }
}
```

What concerns me about this is that the user might obtain a type from the AvailableTypes list (by selecting a combobox item for example) and then use that reference directly rather than creating a clone of the type and using their own reference.

How can I make the list of available types read only so that it doesn't allow any writing or changes to the type instances, forcing the user to create their own clone?

Alternatively is there a better way of providing a list of available types?

Thanks, Andy

Comment: If you want `MyDataType` to be readonly, that should be perfomed in that class. The collection already is read only.

Comment: Are you trying to achieve a creation of some object that is read only to all the world except the creator of the object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get around the problems you've mentioned, you could create a wrapper around your instances, and have the wrapper provide the functionality you require.

For example:

```
    public class TypeDescriptor
    {
        private MyDataType _dataType;

        public TypeDescriptor(MyDataType dataType)
        {
            _dataType = dataType;
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return _dataType.ToString();
        }
    }
```

You class would then look something like:

```
    public static class DataTypes
    {
        public static ReadOnlyCollection<TypeDescriptor> AvailableTypes;

        static DataTypes()
        {
            List<TypeDescriptor> Types = new List<TypeDescriptor>();
            Types.Add(new TypeDescriptor(new MyTypeA()));
            Types.Add(new TypeDescriptor(new MyTypeB()));
            AvailableTypes = new ReadOnlyCollection<TypeDescriptor>(Types);
        }
    }
```

Binding to the list and relying on the ToString() will now result in your data types ToString being called.

Comment: This is the solution that I chose as it is simple and allows me to extend the read only type descriptor class any way I want to support data binding. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Make your custom `Type` class immutable, same as `System.Type` and you dont have to worry. A end user can fetch all the data it wants but he can not modify the object in any way.

**EDIT:** Example of immutable class

Take the following class for instance:

```
public class ImmutablePerson
{
    private readonly string name; //readonly ensures the field can only be set in the object's constructor(s).
    private readonly int age;

    public ImmutablePerson(string name, int age)
    {
         this.name = name;
         this.age = age;
    }

    public int Age { get { return this.age; } } //no setter
    public string Name { get { return this.name; } }

    public ImmutablePerson GrowUp(int years)
    { 
         return new ImmutablePerson(this.name, this.age + years); //does not modify object state, it returns a new object with the new state.
    }
}
```

`ImmutablePerson` is an immutable class. Once created there is no way a consumer can modify it in any way. Notice that the `GrowUp(int years)` method does not modify the state of the object at all, it just returns a new instance of `ImmutablePerson` with the new values.

I hope this helps you understand immutable objects a little better and how they can help you in your particular case.

Comment: If the class is immutable the how can it hold a specific value like other data types can? For example an UInt16 has a 16-bit integer value. For my classes to work as data types they also need to hold a value of some kind.

Comment: Not at all. `System.String` is inmutable for instance. In an inmutable class you can set the object state when creating an instance of the class but once created, you can never modify it. For example: `string s = " hello "; s.Trim();` will not modify `s` (it will still be `" hello "`). `Trim()` however will return a new string with the new value `"hello"`. The same happens with `UInt16`, you set the value when creating it: `Uint16 x = 4;` There is no way you can modify the value of a UInt16 instace once created.

Comment: I just want to know what `Inmutable` is?  A string class is not `inmutable` it is `immutable`.

Comment: @JonH: lol sorry, english is not my language so I sometimes make these kind of mistakes. I'll edit the post. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for showing me an example - it is much clearer to me now!

Answer (score 2):

Create a list of types rather than a list of instances. e.g.

```
List<Type> Types = new List<Type>();
Types.Add(typeof(MyTypeA));
Types.Add(typeof(MyTypeB()));
etc.
```

To answer the comment on binding to a drop down list:

```
MyDropDown.Datasource = Type.Select(t => t.Name);
MyDropDown.DataBind();
```

This will not use the custom property of your classes but it will give you the simple calss name without all the other guff e.g. MyTypeA

Comment: Thanks, however this doesn't look so good when the list is bound to a combobox. The ToString() for the types produces a fully qualified name which isn't user friendly. With my current approach ToString() returns the contents of the user-friendly Name property on each of my custom datatype classes. Any ideas how I can solve this? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You probably shouldn't store instances of your types in the list. Instead you can store types. These can be used to create instances:

```
public static class DataTypes
{
    static ReadOnlyCollection<Type> AvailableTypes;

    static DataTypes()
    {
        List<Type> Types = new List<Type>();
        Types.Add(typeof(MyTypeA));
        Types.Add(typeof(MyTypeB));
        AvailableTypes = new ReadOnlyCollection<MyDataType>(Type);
    }
}
```

You can use `Activator.CreateInstance` to create a concrete instance:

```
Object myType = Activator.CreateInstance(AvailableTypes[0]);
```

Unless your types share a common base type you cannot downcast the result and an `Object` isn't that useful.

Also the use of the term *type* in your code makes my example a bit confusing as I suggest you store the types of something called *type*.

You could consider creating and attribute that you then can apply to `MyTypeA`, `MyTypeB` etc. Then you can build the `AvailableTypes` using reflection and the list will always be up to date with your code. E.g. if you add `MyTypeC` and use the attribute it will automatically be added to the list.

You can also add a display string property to the attribute and use that for display in the combo box. If you want to do that you should store a small object combining the type and the display string in `AvailableTypes`.

Here is an example. Using generic words like *type* and *data* can be confusing so to pick a random name I just use *foo*. Obviously you should use a more descriptive name.

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class, Inherited = false)]
sealed class FooAttribute : Attribute {

  public FooAttribute(String displayName) {
    DisplayName = displayName;
  }

  public String DisplayName { get; private set; }

}
```

You can decorate you classes using this attribute:

```
[Foo("Type A")]
class MyTypeA { ... }

[Foo("Type B")]
class MyTypeB { ... }
```

For the combobox you want a list of factory objects with a nice `ToString` implementation (this class can be improved by adding some error handling which I have left out to save space):

```
class FooFactory {

  readonly Type type;

  public FooFactory(Type type) {
    this.type = type;
    DisplayName = ((FooAttribute) Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(
      type,
      typeof(FooAttribute))
    ).DisplayName;
  }

  public String DisplayName { get; private set; }

  public Object CreateFoo() {
    return Activator.CreateInstance(this.type);
  }

  public override String ToString() {
    return DisplayName;
  }

}
```

Returning `Object` from `CreateFoo` isn't very useful but that is a separate issue.

You can build this list at run-time:

```
var factories = Assembly
  .GetExecutingAssembly()
  .GetTypes()
  .Where(t => Attribute.IsDefined(t, typeof(FooAttribute)))
  .Select(t => new FooFactory(t));
```

Comment: Thanks, however this doesn't look so good when the list is bound to a combobox. The ToString() for the types produces a fully qualified name which isn't user friendly. With my current approach ToString() returns the contents of the user-friendly Name property on each of my custom datatype classes. Any ideas how I can solve this? Thanks.

Comment: You can store a factory object in the combobox that stores the type, has the desired implementation of `ToString` displaying whatever friendly name you want and is able to create an instance.

Comment: Can you please point me to an example or some hints on this approach? I think this is what I need. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for expanding on this approach. I think I can make use of these techniques in my code.

Answer (score 2):

A collection cannot "inject" type modifiers into its members. The collection you have declared is readonly. If you want `MyDataType` to be readonly you must declare that way.

Somthing like :

**EDIT** extended class to have a parse method

```
public class MyDataType
{
    private MyDataType()
    {
        ...
    }

    internal static MyDataType Parse(string someString)
    {
        MyDataType newOne = new MyDataType();
        newOne.Value = ... //int.Parse(someString); ?
    }

    public int Value { get; private set; }
}
```

If the collection stays generic there is no readonly constraint.

You would use it like this, following your example.

```
MyTypeA foo = MyTypeA.Parse(inputString);
if (foo.Value > 4) return;
```

Comment: If I declared MyTypeA as read only then how would it be able to parse a string into an integer value as shown in my example? That requires the integer to be stored somewhere and I don't want that to change for the instances that are in the list.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly sure of what you want but should something like this be ok ?

```
 public static class DataTypes
 {
      static Dictionary<string,Type> AvailableTypes
      = new Dictionary<string,Type>()
      {
           { "MyTypeA", MyTypeA },
           { "MyTypeB", MyTypeB },
           ...
      };
 }
```

That is actually return **types** instead of sample instances of theses types. Thus you would be sure that only new instances would be created by the user of your class.

Then in the calling code :

```
MyTypeA a = Activator.CreateInstance(DataTypes.AvailableTypes["MyTypeA"]);
```